# Application.getsaveasFilename doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I can't execute `Application.getsaveasFilename` several times or when I'm doing many instructions before.

What I don't understand is that if I add an `Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)` before prompting for the dialog box it works.

How can I fix this?

---

My code is very long and I don't know which is revelent to post or not, I'll be glad to add more if you need.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Maybe you can post the few lines where the error happen. Meanwhile, you can read this to understand more regarding getsaveasFilename : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx

Comment: @SiddharthRout  No i don't. Excel just crashes

Comment: Do you have any `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: @keong kenshih  this is how i used it:

  nomFichier = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Base_" & nomTestSelected & "_" & UserForm1.regulation.value, _
            fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xls")

Comment: @SiddharthRout  Yes i have. Is it a problem for excel functions?

Comment: Can you remove it and step though the code using F8 and see where the problrm is?

Comment: @SiddharthRout  it's the same!! excel crashes the second time i RUN the macro even if the step into don't show any problem

Comment: Post your complete macro

Comment: You could put the following code to check whether your file had been saved successfully or not:  If nomFichier <> False Then
 MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
 End If